# how to remove any storage file using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to remove any storage file using flutter?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete or create files in the user's storage with your Flutter app. But, before you do you might have to ask for permission to access the user's file storage.

Then get the file path of the file you want to delete. Maybe `path_provider: ^2.0.11` can be helpful in that case.

Once you got the file path, it's easy as:

```dart
File fileToDelete = File(path);

fileToDelete.delete();
```

You're good to go!